# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on string

Tags: php, database, doctrine

I am trying to save dates to an SQL-database using Doctrine.
The user writes the dates to input-fields using datepicker and they have the format dd.mm.yyyy (german). In the database the dates look like this `"2021-09-30"` or this `"0000-00-00"` if no date is given

I am using this code to set the Input data to the entity:

```
if(isset($formData["startDate"]) and $formData["startDate"] != "") {
    $sD = explode(".", $formData["startDate"]);
    $campaign->setStartDate(($sD[2]."-".$sD[1]."-".$sD[0]));
} else {
    $campaign->setStartDate("0000-00-00")
}
```

But this produces the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on string`.
How can i save the dates to my database?

Here are the field and getter/setter:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
protected $startDate;



/**
 * Set startDate
 *
 * @param integer $startDate
 * @return Campaign
 */
public function setStartDate($startDate)
{
    $this->startDate = $startDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get startDate
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getStartDate()
{
    return $this->startDate;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Not at all, as the error is not produced by me directly, but occurs later in DateType.php

Comment: I am pretty sure i have to turn the string into some dateformat, but everything i am trying, like strtotime() doesn't do the trick either.

Comment: `format()` is a function which is available on the PHP [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, so you're probably meant to supply one of those - it makes sense, given the context. If you're getting an input string in a non-standard format such as the one you described, then use the static function [createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to create a DateTime object from the input data.

Comment: If you want it gone, you can request it by flagging. Duplicates aren't a bad thing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can define your setter/getter with `\DateTimeInterface`, like this

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", options={"default":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"})
 */
 protected $startDate;

/**
 * Set startDate
 *
 * @param \DateTimeInterface $startDate
 * @return Campaign
 */
public function setStartDate(\DateTimeInterface $startDate)
{
    $this->startDate = $startDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get startDate
 *
 * @return \DateTimeInterface
 */
public function getStartDate()
{
    return $this->startDate;
}
```

Then, you should have a better output. Note that `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is an invalid date...

For your error, you can make it like this

```
if(isset($formData["startDate"]) && !empty($formData["startDate"])) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y\.m\.d', $formData["startDate"]);
} else {
    $date = new DateTime('now');
}

$campaign->setStartDate($date);
```

Hope it's help

Comment: This is really nice, thank you. $date = new DateTime('now'); is really good for the startDate, but i am doing the same thing with endDate as well. What would i do if i don't want to have an endDate for an Entity?